# Retrieve stroke-width attribute of d3 axis path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following script I can retrieve the "stroke" attribute of the d3 axis path, but I cannot do the same for the "stroke-width" attribute (the console prints null). Is there a way to retrieve the "stroke-width" attribute so I can use it downstream?

```js
var width = 100,
    height = 100,
    margin = 10;
    
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
     .attr('width', width)
     .attr('height', height);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([margin, width - margin]);

// Add the Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height/2) + ")")
   .attr("class", "xAxis")
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
   .tickValues([0, 10])
   );
   
   
console.log(d3.select(".xAxis path").attr("stroke"))
console.log(d3.select(".xAxis path").attr("stroke-width")) //this returns null
```

```css
.xAxis path{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.xAxis text{
  fill: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the `stroke-width` in the CSS, it has to be `style`, not `attr`.

```
console.log(d3.select(".xAxis path").style("stroke-width"))
//using style as a getter -------------^
```

```js
var width = 100,
    height = 100,
    margin = 10;
    
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
     .attr('width', width)
     .attr('height', height);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([margin, width - margin]);

// Add the Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height/2) + ")")
   .attr("class", "xAxis")
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
   .tickValues([0, 10])
   );
   
   
console.log(d3.select(".xAxis path").attr("stroke"))
console.log(d3.select(".xAxis path").style("stroke-width"))
```

```css
.xAxis path{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.xAxis text{
  fill: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Funny that it works for "stroke" (colour) but not for "stroke-width"

Comment: That's because the default stroke is black. You didn't need to set it in the CSS.